# Alignment in Foundation 5

Tags: html, alignment, zurb-foundation

How I can remove the spaces between the class?

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <img src="/image/my-image.jpg" alt="" /> [ 1 ]
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">[ 2 ]
    </div>
</div>
```

[ 1 ]
The image is centered in reference to my class. large-2.
I would leave it on the left side of the div .large-2

I tried with .text-left and text-right, like:

```
<div class="large-2 columns">
    <div class="text-left">
        <img src="/image/my-image.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some default padding with `columns` -- what you'd want to do is add this:

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-2 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-8 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-2 columns"></div>
</div>
```

That `collapse` class removes the default spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="large-2 columns">
  <img class="left" src="/image/my-image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```